# Gradle not finding server runtime in eclipse project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gradle

I have an Eclipse JavaEE project I am trying to convert to a gradle project.
The code in my project uses jar files from a WebSphere Liberty server runtime.

I have added the server runtime to the classpath and the editor recognizes it and doesn't throw any errors. When I try to build the project with gradle, I get 100+ errors, saying it can't find any of the classes inside the server runtime.

How can I tell gradle to use the server runtime during the build phase?

> build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
targetCompatibility = '1.7'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.company.jsend:JSend:1.0'
    compile 'com.company.network:Network:1.0'
}
```

> settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'ApplicationName'
```

The server code is located at src > main > java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a couple of options for compiling against the the liberty runtime.

#### Find the packages you need in maven central and add them as `providedCompile` dependencies.

Rather than getting the APIs directly from your installed Liberty runtime, you'll get them from Maven central instead. This is preferred, since it allows you to compile your code anywhere, without needing a liberty runtime installed and it means that your build classpath doesn't depend on which features you have installed in your liberty runtime.

E.g.

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0' // All Java EE 7 APIs
    providedCompile 'javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:3.2' // Just the EJB 3.2 APIs
    providedCompile 'com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api:com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api.security:1.2.13' // Liberty security APIs
}
```

You'll usually find the standardized Java EE APIs in a `javax.something` group. If you need the liberty APIs, they're under the `com.ibm.websphere.appserver.api` group.

#### Include jars from a local liberty runtime as `providedCompile` dependencies.

Here we tell Gradle where your liberty runtime is installed and ask it to include the API jars from the runtime in the build classpath.

E.g.

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile fileTree(dir: "${liberty.root}/dev/api/spec")
}
```

Be aware that in this case, the APIs that are available will depend on which features you have installed.

This approach requires you to tell Gradle where your liberty runtime is installed by setting the property `liberty.root` when you run Gradle.

Comment: I ended up locating the jar files locally, and added them all from the CLI tools. Everything appears to be working and compiling! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When developing Java EE application with Gradle, practice is to use javaee-api as providedCompile (if war) or compileOnly (I think Gradle 2.13 and later)

Below is the example

providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'